# Separate easing for Reveal and Hide action

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I have a div (#photographerInfo) with position:fixed that is revealed when a button is clicked. A javascript sets a class on the div that animates it in onto the viewport. When the fullscreen mode is exited, the class is removed.

```
function openFullscreen(){       
    $('#photographerInfo').addClass('showfullscreen');
}

function removeFullscreen(){         
    $('#photographerInfo').removeClass('showfullscreen');
}
```

on #photographerInfo:

```
#photographerInfo{
    animation-delay: 2s;
    transition: all 400ms ease-out;
    right: 0px;
    position:fixed;
}

#photographerInfo.showfullscreen {
    right:30px;
}
```

This is all fine and dandy, but when I remove the class to hide the div, I would like to have easeIn instead of easeOut.

How can this be accomplished?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By switching your `addClass` logic to `toggleClass` [ref](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), and assigning an `ease-in` transition your base class and an `ease-out` transition to your toggle class, you get the effect where the item eases out on display and eases in on hide.

On a side note, I'd recommend styling a class instead of the id. I don't know what your site looks like, but if you ever wanted to expand/reuse your animation logic you may face issues if it only affects one id.

```js
function toggleFullscreen(){       
    $('#photographerInfo').toggleClass('showfullscreen');
}
```

```css
#photographerInfo{
    position:fixed;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
    right: 0;
}

#photographerInfo.showfullscreen {
    right:100px;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="toggleFullscreen();">
Toggle
</button>

<div id="photographerInfo">
  Hello world
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was so simple!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `transition-timing-function` rule in the `.showfullscreen` class.

```
#photographerInfo.showfullscreen {
    right: 30px;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) about `transition-timing-function` property.

Here's an example:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('toggle'),
    animated = false;
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  (animated === false) ? openFullscreen():removeFullscreen();
  animated = !animated;
});
function openFullscreen(){    
  $('#photographerInfo').addClass('showfullscreen');
}

function removeFullscreen() {    
  $('#photographerInfo').removeClass('showfullscreen');
}
```

```css
#photographerInfo{
    animation-delay: 2s;
    transition: all 800ms ease-out;
    right: 0px;
    position:fixed;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #849274;
}

#photographerInfo.showfullscreen {
    right: 130px;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="toggle">Animate</button>
<div id="photographerInfo"></div>
```